# Two short beeps and nothing on the monitor

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I am building a small Mini-ITX computer. But I can not make it boot. When I start the computer I hear two short beeps from the motherboard and nothing is shown on the monitor.

How can I fix this?

The motherboard is a MSI IM-945GSE Option A with an Intel Atom processor and embedded graphics. I have a 1GB Kingston DDR2 memory KVR667D2S5/1G but I have also tested with a 2GB KVR533D2S4/2G. The power supply is a FSP300-60GHS.

I can not find what the two short beeps means in [the manual for the motherboard](http://resources.mini-box.com/online/MBD-I-945GSE/MBD-I-945GSE-manual.pdf).

Comment: This seems to be a similar problem [IM-945GSE-A & 2GB SODIMM won't POST](http://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=128723.0;wap2)

Comment: Does it make the same beeps when you remove all the memory sticks and boot?

Comment: @ayaz: Good suggestion. I removed the memory, and now I get more beeps, but they are much louder. So the two short beeps is probably something else. Maybe it's just the graphics that is broken...?

Comment: should be able to test that if you have a PCI video card sitting around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this beep code mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/670120/what-does-this-beep-code-mean)

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSI's site](http://us.msi.com/support/sup_tshoot.asp) scroll down to the "No Post - Diagnostic codes " section, you'll see a description of beep codes. Depending on what kind of BIOS you have it could mean different things:

> AMI Beep Code
>   Beep Code - Description
>   1 short - DRAMS refresh failure
>   2 short - Parity circuit failure
>   3 short - Base 64k RAM failure
>   4 short - System timer failure
>   5 short - Process failure
>   6 short - Keyboard controller Gate A20 error
>   7 short - Virtual mode exception error
>   8 short - Display memory Read/Write test failure
>   9 short - ROM BIOS checksum failure
>   10 short - CMOS shutdown Read/Write error
>   11 short - Cache Memory error
>   1 long, 3 short - Conventional/Extended memory failure
>   1 long, 8 short - Display/Retrace test failed
>
> AWARD Beep Code
>   Beep Code - Description
>   1 Long, 2 Short - A video error has occurred and the BIOS cannot intialize the video screen to display any additional information
>   Any other beep(s) - RAM problem

Comment: Okey, so it's either the memory (I have tried with two sticks - same beeps) or the graphics card (embedded on the motherboard). So I guess I have to buy a new motherboard.

Comment: See my comment to my question. Response to ayaz.

Comment: @Jonas yes if reseating the RAM doesn't do it, and it's an integrated CPU then call MSI and get an RMA

Comment: I have returned the motherboard to the shop, they removed the battery and said it worked for them. Now when I got the motherboard back I have the same problem again. I have tried with removing the battery but id doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure that everything is plugged in correctly. I did this once, but there was a motherboard cord unplugged (I don't remember what it was). Look very carefully at all the plugs and make sure you didn't miss one. comment back and tell me the outcome.

-Good Luck

Comment: Well there is not much that can go wrong. It should be possible to just connect the power, an USB-keyboard, the SO-DIMM Memory and a DVI monitor, to able to enter the BIOS.

Comment: You said you were building it correct? Building a computer to me means connecting all the necessary parts together (motherboard, processor, RAM, hard drive, etc). If this is what you did, a cable could be disconnected that is supposed to be connected to something. This is what I was talking about, not the keyboard, mouse, monitor, etc.

Comment: Yes, but the CPU and Graphics card is embedded on the motherboard, so I just have to insert a memory stick and power. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I would double check that the proper power supply to motherboard connections are being made.  While you are in there reseat the RAM.

Comment: I have reseat the ram and tried both the 1GB and the 2GB stick. And also ckecked the power. It's actually starts a few seconds and I can restart it with CTRL+ALT+DELETE on the keyboard. But I always get the two short beeps and no video. I think there most be a failure of the motherboard.